# How to pass parameter to constructor when using .getClass()?

Tags: java, reflection, jackson, spring-remoting

I have that line of code and it was working at that version:

```
...
Wrapper<Model> wrapped = restTemplate.getForObject(BASE_URL, Wrapper.class, map);
...
```

However I want to send parameter to constructor:

```
...
Wrapper<Model> wrapped = restTemplate.getForObject(BASE_URL, new Wrapper(Model.class).getClass(), map);
...
```

It throws me an exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class a.b.c.d.model.Wrapper]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream@ef9e8eb; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class a.b.c.d.model.Wrapper]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: org.apache.commons.httpclient.AutoCloseInputStream@ef9e8eb; line: 1, column: 3]
```

How can I send parameter to an object that I will get the class of value of it?

Comment: What class is 'Wrapper'? Is this? --> http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wrapper.class` and `new Wrapper().getClass()` and `new Wrapper(theParam).getClass()` return the same value: `Wrapper.class`. All this if you have sutable constructor, i.e., constructor that is able to get argument `theParam`. In your case class `Wrapper` does not have constructor that accepts argument of type `Class`, so it complains about this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you need is to indicate generic type of Wrapper for Jackson to use. There are couple of ways to do this:

```
Wrapper<Model> value = objectMapper.readValue(source, new TypeReference<Wrapper<Model>>() { });
Wrapper<Model> value = objectMapper.readValue(source, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Wrapper.class, Model.class);
```

I am not sure how either TypeReference or JavaType (which are generics-enabled alternatives to passing Class instances (that are type-erased, i.e. no generics!)) through Spring framework, but I assume it should be possible.

Alternatively, if that can't be made to work, try sub-classing Wrapper -- concrete sub-class WILL actually have information necessary:

public class ModelWrapper extends Wrapper { }
   ModelWrapper wrapped = restTemplate.getForObject(BASE_URL, ModelWrapper.class);